# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on fscanf

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, scanf

the following code gives me a segmentation fault on the second iteration of the for loop at the fscanf,what might be the problem??? is fflush(stdin) used correctly here??? or is there another reason.
the code is supposed to creat an array of type NODE and each index holds a linked list with 32 nodes of integer read from the file.txt

```
FILE *file = fopen ("file.txt", "r");

int count =0;
int x=0;
   for ( x=0; x<=312500; x++)
     {
          while (count <=32)
        {

             fscanf (file, "%d", &temp->num);  

temp->ptr=NULL;


   newNode = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   newNode->num=temp->num;
   newNode->ptr=NULL;



               if (first != 0)

           {

            last->ptr=newNode;
            last=newNode;
            count=count+1;

           }
          else

          {

             first = newNode;
             last = newNode;
             count=count+1;
           }

               fflush(stdin);

       }

          count =0;
          array[x] = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
          array[x]->ptr=first;


         first->ptr=0;
         first=NULL;

         last->ptr=0;
         last=NULL;

        temp->ptr = 0;  
temp=NULL;

       fflush(stdin);
        }

 fclose (file);
```

Comment: also; always check your return values - after malloc and fopen, check returns..

Answer (score 3):

The first iteration of the loops ends by setting

```
temp=NULL;
```

You dereference `NULL` at the start of the second iteration inside

```
fscanf (file, "%d", &temp->num);
```

Your code doesn't show how `temp` was allocated so its hard to say whether you should stop NULLing it or allocate a new instance.

Comment: temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
i have removed the temp=null; statement and the error has gone!